# How can I use ngRepeat with an object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following JS object:

```
var test = {
    "John": {"grade": "A", "age": 18},
    "Jack": {"grade": "B", "age": 19},
    "Jill": {"grade": "C", "age": 18},
    // ...
}
```

I know how to use `ngRepeat` whenever there is array involved, i.e

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in test"
```

But is there a way to use `ngRepeat` when I have an object?

Comment: What you have is not JSON but rather a JavaScript object.  JSON is always a string representation of a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add another level to ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="(name, personInfo) in test">
    <span>{{name}}</span>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in personInfo">
        <label>{{key}}</label>
        <span>{{value}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5v0mcL1o/

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could do a strict array. Does this not work as is, though? If no, maybe this. Untested.

```
// array from obj, then do your thing.

var students = Object.keys(test).map(function (key) {return test[key]});
```

Answer (score -1):

Ng repeats interact over an array, so for this object it is not very useful.... But you can use:

$scope.students = Object.keys(test)

And then interact over students